# break multiple string into each

Tags: c#, winforms

iam just curious, is there a way to break multiple string in cell gridview and store it or display it one by one.

[image]

earlier when i `messagebox.show` it would diplay the whole name or number like 
`abdullah ali ashonie; adefitri; candry`. so what i want is, it display one by one `abdullah ali shonie` then `adefitri` then `candry` and how to store it

sorry for bad english, because i dont quite sure you guys know what i want

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
var parts = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.Split(";".ToCharArray())
```

Just be warned: `String.Split()` has all kinds of pitfalls and gotchas. If you can't put meaningful constraints on the possible values — be **absolutely certain** you won't find things like new-lines or other semi-colon(`;`) characters as part of individual names, have quoted text, etc — you should really look into a dedicated delimited text parser. There are three (at least) built into the .Net Framework (see [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) as one option), and a plethora more on NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I completely understand what you're trying to do, but this is a basic [string split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) example:

```
    string input = "abdullah ali ashonie; adefitri; candry";
    string[] pieces = input.Split(';');
    foreach (var s in pieces) {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Trim());
    }
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qtjs5M).

Comment: well in your fiddle, the second text the first character was `space` so i just need to add `trim()` in `console.writeline(s.trim())` ??

Comment: that's correct.  I updated the example above as well as the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.

For example:

```
 string text = "abdullah ali ashonie; adefitri; candry";

 string[] names = text.Split(';');

 foreach (string name in names)
 {
     System.Console.WriteLine(name);
 }
```

Outputs:

```
abdullah ali ashonie
adefitri
candry
```

[There is some more information here too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

Comment: thanks for reference, i just dont know thats the keyword :)

Comment: well iam using yours but the second and the third got `space` characater in the first char.

Comment: Use [`String.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) on each name, e.g. `System.Console.WriteLine(name.Trim());`